# Date formatiing

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, calendar

While adding a Event in calendar using following format it addz in Calendar Alert as :

```
  "1 day before",
```

But i want as

```
  "At the time of event"
```

Here my code,

```
calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSString *cday,*cmonth,*cyear;
// set today
today = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
//set the current day to show the calendar
NSDateFormatter *temp1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[temp1 setDateFormat:@"dd"];
cday=[temp1 stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"Date checking%@",cday);
[temp1 release];
```

Whats wrong in my code?Can any one please help me to sort out .

Comment: The differece is coming from TimeZone, you are ahead of timezone. Change the timezone and check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably has something to do with time zones. You probably need to set an appropriate value for the timeZone property of your NSDateFormatter object.Please set the time zone to local time zone

```
[temp1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

(or)

[temp1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
```

please put this code :

```
 NSCalendar  *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSString *cday,*cmonth,*cyear;
    // set today
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    //set the current day to show the calendar
    NSDateFormatter *temp1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [temp1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    [temp1 setDateFormat:@"dd"];
    cday=[temp1 stringFromDate:today];
    NSLog(@"Date checking%@",cday);
    [temp1 release];
```

Comment: i did still its adding in the same "1 day before", any other prob

Comment: is there any issue with theinitWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1;

Comment: in ur code today = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]; so this is giving time difference

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26621/discussion-between-fazil-and-ann)

Comment: Regarding Snoozing , Is any way to handle the snoozing time diffrentce?

Comment: sorry i don't have idea about it